# Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in,

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

mes sale el siguiente error cuando insertar datos en phpmyadmin con código php y montado en 000webhost, en el server local trabaja sin problemas.

el codigo que estoy utilizando

```
<?php

  require 'database.php';

  $message = '';

  if (!empty($_POST['nombre']) && !empty($_POST['apellido'])&& !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO reg_usuario (,nombre, apellido, email, password,fecha_registro) VALUES (:nombre,:apellido,:email,:password:fechareg)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
      $stmt->bindParam(':nombre', $_POST['nombre']);
      $stmt->bindParam(':apellido', $_POST['apellido']);
    $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    $fechareg = date("d/m/y");
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
    $stmt->bindParam(':fechareg', $fechareg);


    if ($stmt->execute()) {
      $message = 'Se creo correctamente el Usuario';
    } else {
      $message = 'No se creo el usuario';
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Aquí `,:password:fechareg` tienes un typo pues falta una coma que separé ambas columnas, por eso te dice que no empatan los valores, en caso de ser afirmativa mi observación te comento que tú pregunta que daría cerrada por lo antes expuesto

Comment: Aparte del error que te menciona @BetaM, aquí tienes otro: `INSERT INTO reg_usuario (,nombre, apellido, email, password,fecha_registro)`, es una coma antes de `nombre`. Como consejo, se agradece un poco de orden en el código, por ejemplo, crear las variables primero, y poner todos los `bindParam()` seguidos y en el orden en que están en el `INSERT`. Parece una tontería, pero ayuda mucho a revisar el código, sobre todo si trabajas en equipo.

Comment: También, podrías escribir un código más limpio, en lugar del laaargo `if (  (!empty(), !empty(), !empty(), !empty(), !empty() ) ` podrías aplicar uno por cada dato, usando un ternario y guardando una variable. Luego haces un  `if ($nombre && $apellido....)` y en los `bindParam` usas también `$nombre, $apellido` etc.

Comment: gracias @BetaM  Quite la coma al inicio de :password  y agregue la

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias por la observación soy nuevo en esto pero como dices mas limpio y ordenado lo aplicare ya funciona ya inserta ya quedo mil gracias ...